# If I am deploying a spring boot application to google cloud should I use app engine or compute engine

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am looking to deploy a spring boot REST web application to google cloud. 
I see examples of deploying a spring boot app to both compute engine and app engine.

What are the benefits of each in my scenario?

Answer (score 2):

app engine will be better option. It will provide all the required things like automatically scaling. If you using computer engine then yourself you need to make platform ready. like to need to install java and required environment.